# Migration from Spring 3.x to 4.x (No default constructor was found)

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am n the process of updating Spring and Spring security from 3.0.3 to Spring 4.2.4 and Spring security 4.0.3. I am getting this Error creating bean with.. and no default constructor was found for `ExceptionTranslationFilter` class. This class has two overloaded constructor but a default constructor is not defined. Is there any way around this exception?

Stack trace:

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class com.mercuryinsurance.esignature.ui.webapp.listener.StartupListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/conf/context-ui-security.xml]: Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#676359c2' of type [org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain] while setting constructor argument with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#676359c2': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'exceptionTranslationFilter' while setting constructor argument with key [2]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'exceptionTranslationFilter' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/conf/context-ui-security.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.<init>()
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:313)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:129)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:382)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:157)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:648)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:140)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1143)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
at com.mercuryinsurance.esignature.ui.webapp.listener.StartupListener.contextInitialized(StartupListener.java:15)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#676359c2': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'exceptionTranslationFilter' while setting constructor argument with key [2]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'exceptionTranslationFilter' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/conf/context-ui-security.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.<init>()
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:382)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:157)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:634)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:140)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1143)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:299)
... 29 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'exceptionTranslationFilter' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/conf/context-ui-security.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.<init>()
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1105)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1050)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
... 39 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.<init>()
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:85)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1098)
... 47 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.<init>()
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2892)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2058)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:80)
... 48 more
```

Comment: The `NoSuchMethodException` suggests you're using incompatible versions of libraries (e.g. some things referencing 3.x, some things referencing 4.x). Check your dependencies to make sure they match up. Also [this guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/migrate/current/3-to-4/html5/migrate-3-to-4-jc.html) might prove useful to you.

Comment: Thanks for the guide.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. 
I can't post a straight forward answer because I had to change so many beans that were wired in the config file. In Spring 4.x I found out that most of the setter injection were replaced in favor of constructor injection.

So for every bean that I was getting an error either bean creation or default constructor wasn't found I had to go through the documentation whether the properties were accessible via setter or if they were passed in the constructor and the based on that I had to modify my config file. It wasn't fun but I went through.

Spring migration from 3.x to 4.x was super useful

Answer (score 0):

I have got almost the same error, in my case I specified default constructor according to the Javadoc [Spring Security 4.0.3.RELEASE API - Class ExceptionTranslationFilter](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.3.RELEASE/apidocs/index.html?org/springframework/security/web/access/ExceptionTranslationFilter.html)

```
<b:bean id="etf" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter">
    <b:constructor-arg>
        <b:ref bean="preAuthEntryPoint" />
    </b:constructor-arg>
</b:bean>
```